# Solve gets stuck with rater simple algebraic equation

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[(a^(1/4) + c^(5/3) x)^(6/5) == b && a > 0 && b > 0 && 
  c > 0, x, Reals]
```

is running forever. Why?

Comment: Do not make life harder than necessary. `a^(1/4)` is simply a constant, so you can as well write only `a`. Same for `c`. Then `a+c x== b^(5/6)` and you can again replace `b^(5/6)` by `b` . This leaves the simple equation: `a+b x== b` that you can solve by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for sport. This can be done in two steps.

```
f = ToRadicals[Solve[((a^(1/4) + c^(5/3) x) /. (a^(1/4) + c^(5/3) x) -> z)^(6/5) ==
 b, z, Reals, Assumptions -> b > 0], Assumptions -> b > 0]
```

> `{{z -> b^(5/6)}}`

```
Solve[(a^(1/4) + c^(5/3) x) == z /. f[[1]], x, Reals,Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]
```

> `{{x -> (-a^(1/4) + b^(5/6))/c^(5/3)}}`